# How do I get Loopback to prefer short ids when doing id injection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a loopback app which gives ids like "56dbfa7089223aca7946ca14" when creating models. I would prefer ids like "0" or "73". Is there a way to adjust id-injection practices to have ids start at 0 and increment as base-10 integers?

The data store is MongoDB v2.6.10)
running loopback v2.22 on node v5.7.1 on Ubuntu 15.10

Here's the relevant model.json

```
{
  "name": "Term",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "beginDate": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    },
    "endDate": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "lessons": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Lesson",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "classes": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Class",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "weeklySchedules": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "WeeklySchedule",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: I think you are using MongoDB as your data store.
The generated ID is default ObjectID of MongoDB, you can't avoid that unless setting your own ID and removing idInjection in your model configuration.

Comment: Why not post this as answer?

Comment: Not 100% sure about this

Comment: Please show the model .json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several ways to do it, you can read about them in official [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

It is stated by mongo developers, that is completely ok, to use your own id, if you really need it, so go for it.

However if you do it only because you "dont want ObjectId, because it does not look good", I suggest you, to get used to it.

Comment: I don't care how it looks. There isn't a strong reason why these long ids should be considered a problem.  I prefer them for the purposes easily testing by hand as I go through the initial set up. As such, the most useful solution is to get used to it. Thanks.